# iPhone Location Bug?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm running Xcode 8.1 and iOS 10.0

I've noticed that running the iOS simulator with Location set to City Run, the first three locations come in out of order. Here is an example.

```
<+37.32733927,-122.01971962> +/- 30.00m (speed 3.57 mps / course 177.33) @ 11/8/16, 2:12:42 AM Atlantic Standard Time
<+37.32733927,-122.01971962> +/- 30.00m (speed 3.57 mps / course 177.33) @ 11/8/16, 2:12:38 AM Atlantic Standard Time
<+37.32733927,-122.01971962> +/- 30.00m (speed 3.57 mps / course 177.33) @ 11/8/16, 2:12:42 AM Atlantic Standard Time
<+37.32461541,-122.01985035> +/- 5.00m (speed 3.53 mps / course 276.46) @ 11/8/16, 2:14:01 AM Atlantic Standard Time
<+37.32461920,-122.01989178> +/- 5.00m (speed 3.86 mps / course 281.73) @ 11/8/16, 2:14:02 AM Atlantic Standard Time
<+37.32462267,-122.01993478> +/- 5.00m (speed 3.86 mps / course 281.73) @ 11/8/16, 2:14:03 AM Atlantic Standard Time
```

They all have the same location, accuracy, speed and course. The first and third have the same timestamp which is later than the second. The fourth through the end (no matter how long I let location tracking run), all make sense (each have varying attributes with the timestamps increasing).

All of my code related to location is:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    for newLocation in locations {                        
        // Add location to model
        model.append(newLocation)
        let totalDistance = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: model.totalDistance, unit: .meters)
        distanceLabel.text = totalDistance.description
        debugPrint(newLocation)
    }
}
```

and my `append(_:)` in my model class:

```
func append(_ location: CLLocation) {
    if let oldLocation = _locations.last {
        _totalDistance += location.distance(from: oldLocation)
    }
    _locations.append(location)
}
```

**EDIT:** This is also happening on device. Has anyone else noticed this? I can't recall this happening pre iOS 10.

Comment: Basically you should be ignoring everything in `locations` except the _last_ item.

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager, that is not the case. locations should have an array of CLLocations sorted by time. Also, in the simulator these are coming in one at a time, so I am just looking at the last. I'll double check that on device.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens in the iOS 10 simulator and not the iOS 9 simulator FWIW.

Comment: Any chance you have a device running iOS 9 you can test quick?

Comment: There is definitely some sort of weird caching that causes this sort of thing. You can see this even with something as simple as [`requestionLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation), which sometimes calls `didUpdateLocations` _twice_ even though it isn't supposed to, where the second call appears to be some sort of cached value. Also this might have something to do with why deferred locations don't work at all in iOS 10.

Comment: Excellent. I'll get a bug report sent off.